# Determine bus speed in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory

We have a new Windows Server 2008 R2 server that just went online at a hosting company.  We requested a server with CPUs (Xeon E5540) that would normally run on a 1066 MHz bus.  But the server they delivered had the CPUs upgraded from Xeon E5504s, which would normally run on an 800 MHz bus.  Right now, I don't know if there's a problem or not, but I'm concerned the company the machine might not have memory or a motherboard that can run at the 1066 MHz speed the CPUs can.

Is there any way I can find out the bus speed inside Windows itself, without having to get to the server in person, or install any 3rd-party applications?  This info wasn't available in the System Info interface or the Resource Monitor, at least not anywhere I could find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) it will tell you pretty much everything you want to know about the CPU, Chipset and RAM and definitely will tell you the memory bus speed.

Farseeker's comment prompted me to check something:

```
WMIC MEMORYCHIP
```

This works on Windows Vista, 7, W2K3 & W2K8 doesn't work on XP and W2K.

It will tell you the bus speed and everything else that CPU-Z tells you about the physical RAM. It still wont tell you anything worthwhile from within a VM Guest though.

Comment: +1. AFAIK there's no way in Windows to get the info natively, and CPU-Z doesn't require any installation, so I guess that matches the op's requirements!

Comment: Do you know if it would work in a Hyper-V virtual machine?  The main server, we don't want to install any 3rd-party apps on.  Edit: I see the comment now, "no installation" -- I'll check it out

Comment: If you run it within a Guest Virtual Machine it will only report CPU specific info (that comes directly from the CPU itself to it will be accurate). Any other info that it gets will be limited to the Virtual Hardware as presented by the Hypervisor which will tell you nothing about the real motherboard\chipset\memory. If you run it in the There's no way around that AFAIK, no matter what utility you use it will have to run in the Host OS not one of the VM's.

Comment: @Farseeker - your comment made me double check, apparently WMIC does provide this on W2K3 and newer OS's.

Comment: +.5 for suggesting CPU-Z, and +.5 for the WMIC MemoryChip tip. ;)

Comment: @Helvic, well, I learned something today :)

Answer (score 3):

You can download and install the standalone version of [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/siw-download.html).

Comment: That's a very nice utility - gone straight into my portable apps, thanks for the pointer. :)

Comment: Glad to be of service. ;)